# address changes after a rvalue reference conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  cout << &i << endl;

  const auto &ref = (short&&)i;
  cout << &ref << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Why is `&i` different from `&ref`? `(short&)i` doesn't cause this problem. Does `(short&&)i` generate a temporary variable?

Comment: is it intentional that `i` is `int` but `ref` is a reference to a `short` ?

Comment: Just to be accurate, the title should be "..after a rvalue reference to non-matching type conversion." And a pretty good clue what is going on can be found by using `int&&` instead.

Comment: `short` and `&&` are not important at all, `const auto &ref = (int)i;` gives the same result.

Comment: @Evg the answer section is down there ---vvv

Comment: @Ron applying ta non-overloaded address-of operator against reference is synonymous with applying said-same to the *referenced* (i.e. the referenced object's address). Remove the `short&&` cast and run the code, you'll see identical addresses printed.The only conclusion, therefore, is that `ref` and `i` do not refer to the same object in the OPs case due to that cast.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're doing a different type of cast. The C style explicit conversion cast does always a static cast, if it could be interpreted as a static cast; otherwise it does a reinterpret cast. And/or const cast as needed.

`(short&&)i` is a static cast because it can be interpreted as `static_cast<short&&>(i)`. It creates a temporary `short` object, to which `ref` is bound. Being a different object, it has a different address.

`(short&)i` is a reinterpret cast because it cannot be interpreted as `static_cast<short&>(i)` which is ill formed. It reinterprets the int reference as short reference, and `ref` is bound to the the same object. Note that accessing the object through this reference would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Very nice answer. Is there is a citation for the first paragraph of your answer?

Comment: @P.W hmm I checked the standard and it says *"If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed."* (the list being const,static,static+const,reinterpret,reinterpret+const) which seems to contradict me a bit. It's not clear to me what exactly is the difference between "if a conversion can be interpreted" vs "when the interpretation is not ill-formed".

Comment: Would that mean that `(short&)i` cannot be interpreted as a static cast at all? If it could, it should be, right?

Comment: @P.W Right. You can't do a static cast of an int to a short&, because an int is not a short.

Answer (score 3):

This creates a lvalue reference to a thing that exists:

```
const auto& ref = i;
```

The expressions `&ref` and `&i` will therefore give the same result.

This is also true of:

```
const auto& ref = (int&)i;
```

which is basically the same thing.

However, casting to something that is not a lvalue reference to `T` (so, to a value, or to an rvalue reference of another type!) must create a temporary; this temporary undergoes lifetime extension when bound to `ref`. But now `ref` does not "refer to" `i`, so the address-of results will differ.

[It's actually a little more complicated than that](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref), but you get the idea. Besides, don't write code like this! An `int` is not a `short` and you can't pretend that it is.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it creates a temporary.

Actually the compiler will tell you itself.
Try this:

```
auto &ref = (short&&)i;
cout << &ref << endl;
```

The error says:

> error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'short' cannot bind to a
>   temporary of type 'short'

Test code [here](https://rextester.com/UPJDU27339).

Answer (score 1):

`(short&&)i` creates a temporary, so you take address of an other object, so address might differ.

Comment: In which cases we might get the same address?

Comment: @Evg: I would say, in practice, with correct endianness and "constness", compiler might be allowed to use same address (even if I doubt it does), in similar ways that `"cd"` might be `"abcd" + 2`.